# Shiny - using highcharts to compre two datasets of different length

Tags: r, highcharts

I have two datasets(dataframes) representing two different states with the same variables (year, industry, value).  The length of each dataset is different, not all industries have a value for all years in each state.  The data look something like this:

**ALdata:**

```
YEAR     IND        VALUE  
2001     011999     5.9  
2002     011999     5.7  
2004     011999     5.8  
2005     011999     5.5
```

**MDdata:**

```
YEAR     IND        VALUE  
2001     011999     4.7  
2003     011999     5.2  
2005     011999     5.3
```

I would like to create a highchart column plot that shows bars for both datasets along the same x axis (2001 thru 2005).  Obviously some years will only show one bar, or none.  So far this is all I have:

```
a <- Highcharts$new()
a$chart(type = "column", backgroundColor = NULL)
a$series(name='AL', data = ALdata$value)
a$series(name='MD', data = MDdata$value)
a
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your data always going to be yearly or does it vary? If it is always yearly you can explicitly declare your `xAxis.categories` and then create your data to fill up where data year intersects with category year. See http://jsfiddle.net/wt11ohsr/2/.

Comment: It is always yearly.  I see you manually added the null values into the data so that both series are of the same length.  So I guess my question is how would I do that programmatically in R?  Thanks for your help!